# How to select schema to create table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I created the WSI schema and in trying to create a table under that query, i keep getting the error below. I tried to set the search path to the new schema but I keep running into the same error.

```
ERROR: no schema has been selected to create in
SQL state: 3F000
```

My attempt and the output are as shown below

[image]

Comment: Can you copy/paste the SQL Script and the whole output as text instead of an image, please.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize my screenshot didn't show the script. 

create table wsi.032616to032617_new (column1 varchar, userid varchar, cnt int);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it is the uppercase schema name that is causing the issues.

```
test=# set search_path to WSI;
SET
test=# show search_path;
 search_path 
-------------
 wsi
(1 row)

test=# create table myt (id integer);
ERROR:  no schema has been selected to create in
LINE 1: create table myt (id integer);
                     ^
test=# set search_path to "WSI";
SET
test=# show search_path;
 search_path 
-------------
 "WSI"
(1 row)

test=# create table myt (id integer);
CREATE TABLE
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!